# Increase the number of pages in New Answers to Old Question 10k tool

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

Currently, the number of pages in New Answers to Old Question list is fixed at 25 pages. Since the amount of traffic on SO is very high, 25 pages (500 posts) are filled up with posts from just 4 hours ago.

Is it possible to increase the limit to last 24 hours of posts or 25 pages (whichever is more)?

Comment: Sounds like an awful lot of data to me...

Comment: Before I was a mod, I used to hit that tool *hard*. It is a gold-mine of things to flag; especially spam and Not an Answer. I like this proposal for those who are as addicted to flagging as I was ;) /cc @Undo

Comment: @Undo: The thing is that I don't know how the review queues are doing (I don't visit the most of the queues except for Close and Suggested Edit), but there are garbage even from 4 hours ago, appearing in the New Ans Old Q list.